# Spring MVC petclinic/vets link doesn't work and says - Unable to download vets from localhost

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and try to run PetClinic example.

Currently running with JDBC as a persistence mechanism and it works for everything else but the link on home page "Display all veterinarians" which calls the vetsHandler function in ClinicController class. Up to this point it is working but then it should resolve the view as vets.jsp which it doesn't.

Can somebody please help me here?

Thanks,
Krunal

Answer (score 0):

I had previously in petclinic-servlet.xml the following which I downloaded from SpringSource website

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
       <map>
        <entry key="xml" value="#{vets.contentType}"/> 
        <entry key="atom" value="#{visits.contentType}"/>
       </map>
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="vets" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
    <property name="contentType" value="application/vnd.springsource.samples.petclinic+xml"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"/>
</bean>

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Vets"/>
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
```

So I was able to get to the ClinicController's vetsHandler method but it would not resolve to either vets.jsp or wouldn't display vets.xml

So I made some change in petclinic-servlet.xml as follows

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <!-- <entry key="xml" value="#{vets.contentType}"/>  -->
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>
            <entry key="atom" value="#{visits.contentType}"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                   <property name="classesToBeBound">
                    <list>
                       <value>org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Vets</value>
                    </list>
                   </property>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>      
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

And commented out the bean with id="vets" and ran it again it works great.
So if my URI is /vets then it would resolve to vets.jsp and if it is vets.xml then it would resolve to xml display.

If I only change the above contentType to just "application/xml" for beand("vets") then any request to /vets will resolve to vets.xml

But I still don't understand the below property value of the bean (id="vets") which has property  contentType value = "application/vnd.springsource.samples.petclinic+xml"

Can somebody tell me what is this vnd.springsource.samples.petclinic+xml?
Did they make mistake here instead of org.springframework.samples.petclinic+xml?